# MessageListRequest function not available in Twilio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

I am working to develop project and I need to implement send/receive sms functionality. I found code from some resources to get(inbound) sms but when I tried to implement in my project I am wonder that MessageListRequest and MessageResult  functions are not available in Twilio. Have any one of you idea?

```
var client = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
            var request = new MessageListRequest();
            MessageResult messages = client.ListMessages(request);
```

Comment: This means that the Twilio Library you are using does not have those classes. You need to check what is the type of argument of method `client.ListMessages` and you need to create an object of that type to call this method.

Comment: TwilioClient.Init(AccountSid, AuthToken);
 var messages = MessageResource.Read();

is the line of code which gave me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are reading the documentation for version 4 of the C# Twilio library. We have recently released version 5 of the [C# Twilio library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp) which accesses lists of messages differently. Here is an example of how you would list messages in version 5:

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;

class Example
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        const string accountSid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID";
        const string authToken = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var messages = MessageResource.Read();

        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps at all.